# Need help to make my python script work

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script that can be used to reformat a FASTA file into a two column, table - delimited table as shown in this image above. The script should take the name of the input file from the command line, and the results should go to STDOUT.

Any help will be appreciated! So this what I've so far:

```
#/user/bin/env python
import sys
import re
file_object = open(sys.argv[1])
for some_line in file_object:
       if re.search('>', some_line):
              sys.stdout.write(some_line.strip('\n')+ '\t')
       else:
             if re.search('^\w+', some_line):
                          sys.stdout.write(some_line.strip('w')
```

Expected output:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: What problem(s) are you having with this code (besides syntax errors)?

Comment: I'm getting this IndentationError which says that unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Then start by fixing that.

Comment: @etet112: Just switch each tab in your code to 4 spaces and `IndentationError` won't appear anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else is not aligned with the corresponding  if statement. Anyway I recommend that you get rid of the re package if you can. This example, would be faster:

```
#/user/bin/env python
import sys
file_object = open(sys.argv[1])
for some_line in file_object:
   if some_line.startswith('>'):
          sys.stdout.write(some_line.strip('\n') + '\t')
   else:
          sys.stdout.write(some_line)
```